# How can I display two headings on a single table of contents line in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I am using MS Word 365 on Windows 10. Below is a sample two line heading to be used on the top of the first page of each chapter:

```
Chapter One 
The Journey Begins
```

The first heading is applied to the text "Chapter 1". The second heading is applied to the text "The Journey Begins".

So basically the first page of each chapter is to have a chapter number using a heading such as Heading_1 followed by a second line with its text using Heading_2.

What I need is for the two headings to be shown in the table of contents on the same line **(Desired Effect)**:

```
Chapter One - The Journey Begins .................. 1
```

The problem is the table contents ends up listing the headings as follows:

```
Chapter One ........................................1

    The Journey Begins.............................1
```

How can I get the format for the listed chapters to show like the desired effect above? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Insert a `TC` field at the beginning of each chapter. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, and type the combination of heading text as you want it to appear in the TOC (e.g., **Chapter One – The Journey Begins**). The level should automatically be set to **1**. Click **Mark**.

(If you're comfortable working with field codes, you can include `STYLEREF` fields inside each `TC` field, so that the text from each pair of headings is automatically pulled in for you. That way, you don't have to manually type the text in each `TC` field and manually update it if you later decide to change the chapter number and/or title. You can also copy and paste the field to each subsequent chapter after you've created it for the first chapter.)

Then insert a custom TOC that's built from field codes. On the **References** tab, click **Table of Contents** > **Custom Table of Contents**, click **Options**, and then select the **Table entry fields** check box, clearing the **Styles** check box (assuming you don't want non-chapter headings included in the TOC).

Comment: [This site](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/StyleRef.htm) explains the styleref idea

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want the TOC looking something like this:

[image]

To do that I selected the entire broken paragraph "Chapter 1 - The Journey Begins" including the paragraph mark and assigned it a Heading 1 Style.

Then I selected just "The Journey Begins" and I did not select the paragraph mark. I assigned this a Heading 2 Style.

The technique is called a Linked Style and it's best done with the paragraph pilcrows showing so that you know what you are capturing in the selection. Turn on the hidden characters from the Home tab by clicking the Pilcrow toggle button.

As you can see the dash becomes a bit of an issue, if you could live without the dash then it would look cleaner in the document.

The other option would be to build the TOC by hand using reference fields pointing to bookmarks on each Heading 1 and Heading 2 style. You could then get the dash back ... seems like a lot of work though.